# The issue with AngularJS function that produces post back

Tags: angularjs, postback

We have ASP.NET application and there's a page with AngularJS code. There is a hyperlink on that page with text that switches between "Select all" and "Unselect all" when you click it. By clicking the hyperlink you can select and unselect the group of check boxes. The issue is when I didn't have "form" tag on the page, there was no post back, which is fine. But, I needed to add "form" tag and clicking hyperlink started to produce post back, which is undesired. I'm not sure why. So, my question is - what's going on and how to keep "form" tag and prevent page post back?

Here's the code:

1) Main HTML (without "form" tag there is no post back, but I need "form" tag):

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Default_New.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Concert.Default_New" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="site" TagName="header" Src="includes/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="site" TagName="head" Src="includes/Head.ascx" %>

<!doctype html>

<html id="ng-app" ng-app="cashdeskActionSearchApp">
    <head>
        <site:head id="Head" runat="Server" />        
        <link href="bootstrap/v3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/actions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/new_search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="includes/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/moment.ru.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="bootstrap/v3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="angular/1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/1.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="angular/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_ru.js"></script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/services.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/CashdeskActionSearchApp.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#333333" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <site:header id="HeaderInclude" runat="server"/>
            <div ng-view class="container-fluid"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) The part of view that goes to ng-view on main HTML:

```
<div id="search_categories_filter">
    <label>Типы мероприятий:</label><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-mini" ng-click="UpdateCheckBoxes()">
        <span ng-show="checkBoxesState">Select all</span>
        <span ng-hide="checkBoxesState">Unselect all</span>
    </button>
    <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="at in actionsQuery.actionTypes">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="at.checked">{{at.Description}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3) AngularJS:

```
$scope.UpdateCheckBoxes = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.actionsQuery.actionTypes, function(cb) {
        cb.checked = $scope.checkBoxesState;
    });
    $scope.checkBoxesState = !$scope.checkBoxesState;
};

$scope.checkBoxesState = false;
```

Comment: do you really need runat="sever" inside the form? Angular will not submit the form to the server unless the form has an action attribute specified. remove the runat="server", if not reqired.

Comment: I need it because another functionality requires it.

Comment: But, why does post back happen? It's client code.

Comment: I've solved the issue. Actually, I'm using bootstrap css library to style the toggle button and its type is "submit" by default. But, when I put type to be "button" like this: <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-mini" ng-click="UpdateCheckBoxes()">, everything works fine, which means no post back. Thanks anyway.